# problems with codeigniter radio button form

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Iam a beginner in php and codeigniteran I have a problem concerning a survey vote form Iam creating in codeigniter. I have no idea how many answers the creater of a survey writes so I must code a dynamic page where the user sees as many radio buttons as answeres.

controller:

```
public function vote($frage_id){

        if(!$this->ion_auth->logged_in()){
            redirect('auth/login');
        }

        $antworten = $this->antwort_model->getbyFrageid($frage_id);
        $frage = $this->fragen_model->get($frage_id);

        foreach($antworten as $antwort){
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('antworten',$antwort['inhalt']);
        }

        if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){

            $data = array(
                'frage' => $frage,
                'antworten' => $antworten
            );

            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('antwort/vote', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
            print_r($antworten);



        }
        else{
            $antwort_id;
            foreach($antworten as $antwort){

                if($antwort['inhalt'] = $this->input->post('antworten')){
                    $antwort_id = $antwort['id'];
                }
            }
            $user_id = $this->ion_auth->get_user_id();
            $this->antwort_model->set($antwort_id,$user_id);
            redirect('umfrage/display/'.$frage['umfrage_id']);

        }
    }
}
```

view;

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<h1><?php echo $frage['inhalt'];?></h1>

<?php echo form_open('antwort/vote/'.$frage['id']); ?>
    <?php foreach($antworten as $antwort){ ?>
        <label for="antworten" ><?php echo $antwort['inhalt'];?></label>
        <input type="radio" name="antworten" value = "<?php $antwort['inhalt'];?>"<?=set_radio('antworten',$antwort['inhalt'])?> /><br />

    <?php } ?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

for some reason the form_validation() always returns false.

pls help

thx in advance

Comment: name attribute of radio buttons need to be the same to form a group, this is basic html, read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio

Comment: IF you look at your HTML Source on the browser to see what HTML was generated you should see you have to find a few more

Answer (score 0):

IF you look at your HTML Source on the browser to see what HTML is neing generated you should see you have to find a few more 'echo' commands.

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<h1><?php echo $frage['inhalt'];?></h1>
<?php echo form_open('antwort/vote/'.$frage['id']); ?>
    <?php foreach($antworten as $antwort){ ?>
        <label for="<?php $antwort['inhalt'];?>" ><?php echo $antwort['inhalt'];?></label>
        <input type="radio" name="<?php $antwort['inhalt'];?>" value = "<?php $antwort['inhalt'];?>" /><br />
    <?php } ?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Antwort abgeben" />
</form>
```

Needs a few more echo statements but its is better to use `<?=` than `<?php echo` ( as some folks forget the echo...)

```
<?= validation_errors(); ?>
<h1><?= $frage['inhalt'];?></h1>
<?= form_open('antwort/vote/'.$frage['id']); ?>
    <?php foreach($antworten as $antwort){ ?>
        <label for="<?= $antwort['inhalt'];?>" ><?= $antwort['inhalt'];?></label>
        <input type="radio" name="<?= $antwort['inhalt'];?>" value = "<?= $antwort['inhalt'];?>" /><br />
    <?php } ?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Antwort abgeben" />
</form>
```

And we could add a little less confusion with curly braces in HTML by using https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

```
<?= validation_errors(); ?>
<h1><?= $frage['inhalt'];?></h1>

<?= form_open('antwort/vote/'.$frage['id']); ?>

<?php foreach($antworten as $antwort): ?>
    <label for="<?= $antwort['inhalt'];?>"><?= $antwort['inhalt'];?></label>
    <input type="radio" name="<?= $antwort['inhalt'];?>" value = "<?= $antwort['inhalt'];?>"><br>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Antwort abgeben">
</form>
```